# how could i change the dropdown list default value to another value

Tags: php, jquery, html

This code is displaying the dropdown value in textbox on selection. But i want to display my own values in textbox instead of those default values(Default values of dropdown). how could i do that thing . I have a text box with id "#amount".

This is HTML code:

```
    <select id="d-name" class="form-control" name="menu">
     <option value="Left Chest">Left Chest</option>
     <option value="Simple back">Simple back</option>
     <option value="Complex back">Complex back</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" id="amount" />
```

This is javascript code:

```
 jQuery('#d-name').change(function(e){
     var selectedValue = jQuery(this).val();
     jQuery("#amount").val(selectedValue);
  });
```

Comment: What values do you want to show? You can supply any value you like to `val()`. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @Rory ...i want to show "$20" instead of "Left Chest"

Comment: See the documentation od `.val()` method and you will surely find the answer

Comment: And where will the `$20` value come from? I'd suggest adding some `data` attributes to the `option` elements.

Comment: Is this what you mean Mukii? Replace the value in the option.

 <select id="d-name" class="form-control" name="menu">
     <option value="$20">Left Chest</option>
     <option value="Simple back">Simple back</option>
     <option value="Complex back">Complex back</option>
    </select>

Comment: @Rory...can i change the default value using jQuery....is it possible???

Comment: @Michael..yeah..it is....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use some conditions -

```
var selectedValue = jQuery(this).val();
var amount = '$0';
if(selectedValue == 'Left Chest')
    amount = '$20';
else if (selectedValue == 'Simple back')
    amount = '$30';
...

jQuery("#amount").val(amount);
```

You can also use `switch cases`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also change the amount by using **switch case**:

```js
jQuery('#d-name').change(function(e){
var selectedValue = jQuery(this).val();

switch(selectedValue) {
 case "Left Chest":
 amount = "$20"; // amount which u need
 break;
 case "Simple back":
 amount = "Simple back"; // or amount if u need
 break;
 case "Complex back":
 amount = "Complex back"; // or amount if u need
 break;
 default:
 amount = "";
}  

jQuery("#amount").val(amount);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="d-name" class="form-control" name="menu">
 <option value="Left Chest">Left Chest</option>
 <option value="Simple back">Simple back</option>
 <option value="Complex back">Complex back</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="amount" />
```

Comment: @Mukiikumar: glad to help u.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<select id="d-name" class="form-control" name="menu">
     <option value="&#36;20">Left Chest</option>
     <option value="Simple back">Simple back</option>
     <option value="Complex back">Complex back</option>
</select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x6f3k165/1/

Comment: You are right saying but somehow  i can't change the values. but i got the solution now..anyway thanks for your response..

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
<select id="d-name" class="form-control" name="menu">
     <option>Please select...</option>
     <option value="$20">Left Chest</option>
     <option value="Simple back">Simple back</option>
     <option value="Complex back">Complex back</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="amount" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#d-name').change(function(e){
     var selectedValue = $(this).val();
     $("#amount").val(selectedValue);
  });
</script>
```